# Understanding extra arguments in the Y Combinator in Scheme

Tags: scheme, y-combinator

According to [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Scheme), the Y Combinator in Scheme is implemented as

```
(define Y
  (λ (h)
    ((λ (x) (x x))
     (λ (g)
       (h (λ args (apply (g g) args)))))))
```

Of course, the traditional Y Combinator is **λf.(λx. f(x x))(λx. f(x x))**

My question, then, is about `h` and `args`, which don't appear in the mathematical definition, and about `apply`, which seems like it should either be in both halves of the Combinator or in neither.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: The difference is due to the fact that in pure lambda calculus each function takes one and only one argument, while in Scheme a function can have zero or more than one argument. You can see this from the notation used: `λ args` binds args to the entire list of arguments, and `apply` is needed since the result of `(g g)` must be applied to all the argoments, and this cannot be written in Scheme with a direct notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start off with the lambda calculus version traslated to Scheme:

```scm
(λ (f) 
 ((λ (x) (f (x x)))
  (λ (x) (f (x x)))))
```

I'd like to simplify this since I see `(λ (x) (f x x))` is repeated twice. You can substitute the beginning there to this:

```scm
(λ (f) 
 ((λ (b) (b b))
  (λ (x) (f (x x)))))
```

Scheme is an eager language so it will go into an infinite loop. In order to avoid that we make a proxy.. Imagine you have `+` that takes two numbers, you can substitute it with `(λ (a b) (+ a b))` without the result being changed. Lets do that with the code:

```scm
(λ (f) 
 ((λ (b) (b b))
  (λ (x) (f (λ (p) ((x x) p))))))
```

Actully this has its own name. It's called the Z combinator. `(x x)` is not done when `f` is applied only when the supplied proxy is applied. Delayed one step. It might look strange but I know `(x x)` becomes a function so this is exactly the same as my `+` substitution above.

In Lambda calculus all functions takes one argument. If you see `f x y` it's actually the same as `((f x) y)` in Scheme. If you want it to work with functions of all arities your substitution needs to reflect that. In Scheme we have rest arguments and `apply` to do this.

```scm
(λ (f) 
 ((λ (b) (b b))
  (λ (x) (f (λ p (apply (x x) p))))))
```

This isn't neede if you only are going to use one arity functions as in lambda calculus.

Notice that in your code you use `h` instead of `f`. It doesn't really matter what you call the variables. This is the same code with different names. So this is the same:

```scm
(λ (rec-fun) 
 ((λ (yfun) (yfun yfun))
  (λ (self) (rec-fun (λ args (apply (self self) args))))))
```

Needless to say `(yfun yfun)` and `(self self)` does the same thing.